# React JS : Upload CSV file To Amazon S3 using AWS credentials

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I want to upload CSV file using react S3 Uploader. I have AWS credentials as well. But I don't know how to use it in React JS.

Below is the code I have used.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import ReactS3Uploader from "react-s3-uploader";


 saveUploaderReference = uploader => {
    if (uploader) {
      this.uploaderReference = uploader;
    }
  };
  
  
  getSignedUrl = (file) => {
     console.log("File : " , file)
  };

  


<ReactS3Uploader
            ref={this.saveUploaderReference}
            getSignedUrl={this.getSignedUrl}
            s3path="temp/"
            uploadRequestHeaders={{}}
            contentDisposition="auto"
            scrubFilename={filename => this.filename}
            autoUpload={true}
            multiple={false}
          />
```

I don't know where to use AWS credentials.

I have accessKeyID & secretAccessID. I don't know where to use it.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the credentials to `react-s3-uploader` directly. This is would be a **HUGE** security problem.

You have at least 2 ways of handling this:

- use [presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). Which is a way that you give access to an S3 item to upload items without having credentials (credentials are actually in the url). You'll need a backend for doing this. This is also the way that `react-s3-uploader` recommends to do it
- use an [AWS Cognito Identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html) for unauth users.

Comment: thank you for your answer. There is no backend API for that. the backend developer will take the file path from the AWS S3 Bucket. so I have to upload the file from the front.

Comment: Then try to use Cognito. You need to do a little bit of configuration on the AWS side, but it will work.

Comment: I am new to it.. is there any working example ? it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Radu Diță mentioned already in the second option, use AWS Cognito for that. No need to setup your own backend server + API.

Also, Amplify helps you when you develop with React + AWS.

Here is a good example for your scenario:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-login-page.html

Comment: I am new to it.. is there any working example ? it would be helpful

Comment: Here is a step-by-step guide to get you started: https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/