# How to upload csv string to amazon-s3 as a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, amazon-s3, upload

I tried sending a blob of a csv file, but I'm getting 204 response - no content. so i guess that one is not supported.

here is my current code:

```
const csvString = "aaa,bbb,ccc"; 
const csvFile = new Blob([csvString], { type: "text/csv" });
const fd = new FormData(); 

fd.append("file", csvFile); 
fd.append("key", "..."); 
fd.append("AWSAccessKEyId", "..."); 
fd.append("policy", "..."); 
fd.append("signature", "..."); 

fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: fd, });
```

Comment: Please ask specific questions and explain the research you have done.

Comment: i'll try to be clearer - how do i upload a csv string to the server as a file?
From the research i've done - i can send the csv as a blob, but i'm not sure how it works with the s3 bucket that is expecting a csv file

Comment: I suggest you revise your question to reflect your actual problem which seems to be _How to upload a CSV string to a amazon-s3 bucket as a file_ (or similar). Plus, please include your code so far and explain where you're stuck with it. If your problem is more general like how to do it in principle I recommend finding a tutorial and/or reading documentation first – you're very likely not the first one to upload a CSV file in such a context. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @IvoMori for your fast and helpful advice.
I updated my question

Comment: Possibly, this existing Q/A already answers your question: [React JS : Upload CSV file To Amazon S3 using AWS credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60994199/5698098).